# Vue reactivity in debug mode

Tags: javascript, debugging, vue.js

I can not catch the moment when `activeUpdate` is `wrappedUpdate function`
When it starts `activeUpdate` is `undefined`.
I observe `state` then just call `state.count` for `get()` and from here to `dep.depend`
but in `depend function` inside `activeUpdate` is `undefined` and Set will not add subscriber.
Then `autorun` and `activeUpdate=null`.
When debug this code `state.count++` it debugs first `get()` then `set()`
but in `get()` `activeUpdate` is `null`.I think (because of debugging).
Where I make mistake?

```
function observe(obj) {

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      let internalValue = obj[key]
      let dep = new Dep()
      Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
        get() {
          dep.depend()
          return internalValue
        },
        set(newValue) {
          const isChanged = internalValue !== newValue
          if (isChanged) {
            internalValue = newValue
            dep.notify()
          }
        }
      })
    })
  }

  class Dep {
    constructor() {
      this.subscribers = new Set()
    }

    depend() {
      if (activeUpdate) {
        // register the current active update as a subscriber
        this.subscribers.add(activeUpdate)
      }
    }

    notify() {
      // run all subscriber functions
      this.subscribers.forEach(subscriber => subscriber())
    }
  }

  let activeUpdate

  function autorun(update) {
    function wrappedUpdate() {
      activeUpdate = wrappedUpdate
      update()
      activeUpdate = null
    }
    wrappedUpdate()
  }


  const state = {
    count: 0
  }

  observe(state)

  state.count;

  autorun(() => {
    console.log(`count is: ${state.count}`)
  })

  state.count++
```

Comment: I think moving up your `let activeUpdate` to the top may fix it. `let` and `const` are not hoisted like `var` was, so I assume that the first `activeUpdate` is translated to `window.activeUpdate`, and the second set is the local variable.

Comment: `activeUpdate` is only ever `undefined` when the line `state.count;` executes. That's because at that point, there is no `activeUpdate`; there is not yet any function that depends on `state.count`. It's not until the autorun is executed that there are any dependencies. In other words, I don't think there is anything wrong with what you wrote. The reactivity model is about capturing functions that *depend* on the observed state.